# How to handle arabic form fields properly from classic asp?

Tags: t-sql, asp-classic, arabic

I have t-sql scalar function to validate logins, which works nicely when asked from management studio:

```
select dbo.getLogin(N'نصير الفتلاوي',N'pass')

returns 1
```

when used from asp page with form fields as arguments, it returns 0 although constructed sql when pasted in sql management studio returns 1

If user name doesn't use arabic alphabet code then it works from asp as well.

The SQL Server version is 2008, IIS is 7.5 running on Windows Server 2003.
It behaves the same in IE 10 and Firefox.

ASP page charset is utf-8 set with meta directive.

Answer (score 0):

When you call SQL Server from ASP, your parameters must be nvarchar. Not varchar.

This is the same as adding the `N` prefix to the raw SQL constants

Comment: I call server directly with sql select statement - not with command and parameters. My sql statement is with N prefix exactly as shown in original question - here is the exact code: `  sql="select dbo.getLogin(N'" & uname & "',N'" & pass & "')"
Response.Write("<p>Debug: " & sql & "<p>")
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql, cnn
res=rs(0)
response.write("<p>Debug: getLogin:" & res & "<p>")
`

Comment: @user2299523: that's open to SQL injection. Use parameters. And use SQL profiler to see what SQL is actually being sent